# SDL.Cairo.Canvas not found even if the newest version of SDL(0.6.6.0) has been installed

Tags: haskell, sdl

Right after I installed the newest version of haskell binding version of SDL(0.6.6.0), though I can import SDL.Cairo, I still can not import SDL.Cairo.Canvas:

```
Prelude> install SDL.Cairo.Canvas

<interactive>:1:9: error:
    Not in scope: data constructor ‘SDL.Cairo.Canvas’
    No module named ‘SDL.Cairo’ is imported.
Prelude> import SDL.Cairo.Canvas as Canvas

<no location info>: error:
    Could not find module ‘SDL.Cairo.Canvas’
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
```

So, is SDL.Cairo.Canvas only available in the older versions? Or is it caused by incorrect installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SDL.Cairo.Canvas` is not in the sdl2 package. It is in older versions of the [sdl2-cairo](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sdl2-cairo) package (before 0.2). You can install that with cabal or stack or whatever else you use to install packages.

Alternatively one can find the equivalent module in [cairo-canvas](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cairo-canvas) as `Graphics.Rendering.Cairo.Canvas`.